# How to add graph to website?

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm a beginner here and need help. I have this code, which works and outputs a graph in my browser (if this is the only code in php file). I don't know how to add text below or above just like any other site. When I try, it returns my whole code in the browser. How do I go on about this?

```
<?php 
  // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
  require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
  require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_line.php');
  // Some data
  $ydata = array(11,3,8,12,5,1,9,8,5,7);
  // Create the graph. These two calls are always required
  $graph = new Graph(350,250);
  $graph->SetScale('textlin');
  // Create the linear plot
  $lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);
  $lineplot->SetColor('blue');
  // Add the plot to the graph
  $graph->Add($lineplot);
  // Display the graph
  $graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is quite simply:

```
<img src="graph.php">
```

Put that in a separate HTML file or PHP script. You cannot output the image and text in the same script / web page. It needs to be separated.

Don't worry about the `.php` extension for the image `src=` attribute. It will display despite the lack of `.jpeg` extension. (The Graph class already outputs the correct MIME type I assume.)

Comment: That worked! Like you said, quite simple! Could you assist me on one more question? The reason I'm doing this is to get a RADAR GRAPH to compare two players in their skills. I have MYSQL database which has the table with the columns : player name, defense, offense, experience. I have checkboxes created, but I'm not sure how I would go on about ONLY comparing TWO players. Do you think this can be done with radar graph? Once again, thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: No idea how the graph and your database are related. Certainly warrants a separate question (if the question complexity is not just using two $_POST["checkbox"] values and querying the database for two entries).

Comment: That's pretty much it, I want to get the values of those two records (mysql) and just draw (using jpgraph). If the code to draw a graph is in a separate file, how do I send the values to be used in drawing a radar graph? It's just so complicated to a beginner like me...

Comment: I think I got it. You just need to use `<img src="graph.php?id=1111">` and `<img src="graph.php?id=2222">` on the second page which compares the two graphs. If you have a submit form with input fields or checkboxes, the form redirects them to a `comparegraphs.php?first=1111&second=2222` page for example. Then somehow use `$_GET["first"]` to pass on the `?id=` parameter `echo "<img src='graph.php?id=$number'>";` and retrieve it as $_GET["id"]` in the graph.php script.

Comment: Thanks! I think I know what you mean. You've been a great help!

Comment: Note: seen your other question. You should have tagged that `[php]` - else nobody sees them. Also if you have solved your problem, please post your own answer there (for other users who might stumble over it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on PHP, but I believe that all "require" are supposed to be made before any content is output. Otherwise, the normal HTML/XHTML syntax and formatting take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used this library, but I'm assuming the image is output directly to the browser. It's probably easiest to create a new HTML document (or whatever the rest of your site is powered by) and include this as an image, with the image's `src` being the name of this script.